# In-plane right Cauchy Green tensor for a 2D manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Consider a surface in a 3D Cartesian frame undergoing a deformation - I'm looking for a derivation of the right Cauchy Green tensor (the metric of the deformation) **in the tangent plane of the surface**.

[image]

A point $\mathbf{X}$ in the initial configuration (analogously, $\mathbf{x}$ in the deformed configuration) is given by a mapping of curvilinear coordinates in a parametric plane:
$$
\begin{split}
\mathbf{X} &=\phi_X(\xi^1, \xi^2),  &\quad (\xi^1, \xi^2) \in  \mathbb{R}^2, \quad \mathbf{X} \in \mathbb{R}^3\\
\\
\mathbf{x}&=\phi_x(\xi^1, \xi^2),  &\quad (\xi^1, \xi^2) \in  \mathbb{R}^2, \quad \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^3
\end{split}
$$

For the initial surface, a covariant tangent basis is defined as
$$
\mathbf{G}_\alpha = \frac{\partial X^m}{\partial \xi^\alpha} \mathbf{e_m}.
$$ Therefore the transformation from the parametric to the initial configuration can be described by the deformation gradient
$$
\mathbf{F}_0 = \frac{\partial\mathbf{X}}{\partial\mathbf{\xi}}\in\mathbb{R}^{3\times2}
$$ and the covariant components of the metric tensor
$$
\mathbf{G}=\mathbf{F}_0^T \mathbf{F}_0\in\mathbb{S}^{2}_+
$$  of the initial surface can be obtained as
$$
G_{\alpha\beta} = G_\alpha \cdot G_\beta. 
$$
Similarly, for the deformed surface we have
$$
\mathbf{g}_\alpha = \frac{\partial x^m}{\partial \xi^\alpha} \mathbf{e_m},\quad \mathbf{F}_n = \frac{\partial\mathbf{x}}{\partial\mathbf{\xi}}\in\mathbb{R}^{3\times2},\quad\mathbf{g} = \mathbf{F}_n^T \mathbf{F}_n\in\mathbb{S}^{2}_+
$$ where $g_{\alpha\beta} = g_\alpha \cdot g_\beta $.

The contravariant components of the bases and metrics are denoted by $\mathbf{G}^{\alpha}$, $\mathbf{g}^{\alpha}$ and $G^{\alpha\beta}  $ , $g^{\alpha\beta}$, respectively.

The actual **material** deformation from the initial to deformed surface is given by the deformation gradient
$$
\mathbf{F}=\frac{\partial\mathbf{x}}{\partial\mathbf{X}}=\mathbf{g}_\alpha \otimes \mathbf{G}^\alpha\in\mathbb{R}^{3\times3}
$$ The right Cauchy Green tensor is thus $\mathbf{C}=\mathbf{F}^T \mathbf{F}\in\mathbb{S}^{3}$. Now note that $\mathbf{F}$ and $\mathbf{C}$ are rank 2 i.e. have a null space along the normal of the surface, which is spanned by vectors $\mathbf{v}$ for which $\mathbf{F}^T \mathbf{v} =\mathbf{0}$.
Therefore the *in-plane deformation* (the deformation in the tangent plane) can be described by a tensor $\mathbf{\bar{C}}$ whose components form a 2x2 matrix.

**Question 1**. What is the correct expression for $\mathbf{\bar{C}}$?

The desired matrix $\mathbf{\bar{C}}$ can be obtained as the submatrix of the following change of basis operation:
$$
\mathbf{P}^{-1}\mathbf{C}\mathbf{P} = \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{\bar{C}}&&0 \\ 0&&0 \end{bmatrix},
$$ where $\mathbf{P}$ is formed by the columns of the initial basis and the surface normal, $\mathbf{P}=[\mathbf{G}_1 | \mathbf{G}_2 | \mathbf{G}_1 \times \mathbf{G}_2 ]$.

**Question 2**. How can I obtain $\mathbf{\bar{C}}$ directly using the metrics $\mathbf{{G}}$ and $\mathbf{{g}}$?

Comment: Are you sure you want $\mathbf{P}^{-1}$ and not $\mathbf{P}^T$ in the chance of basis formula? Using the transpose is more natural giving how $\mathbf{C}$ is defined and preserves the symmetry of $\bar{\mathbf{C}}$. Anyway, using the transpose and following your definitions, the answer seems to be just $\bar{C}_{\alpha\beta} = g_{\alpha\beta}$, using the relation $\mathbf{G}^\alpha \mathbf{G}_\beta = \delta^\alpha_\beta$.

Comment: Hi @IgorKhavkine I added an illustration to the question for clarity; $\bar{C}_{\alpha \beta}$ can't be equal to ${g}_{\alpha \beta}$. We have  $\mathbf{g} = \mathbf{F}_0^{T} \mathbf{C} \mathbf{F}_0$ so in the tangent plane $\mathbf{F}_0$ is 2x2 and it seems that $\mathbf{\bar{C}} = \mathbf{F}_0^{-T} \mathbf{g} \mathbf{F}_0^{-1}$... is the answer just $ \bar{C}_{\alpha \beta} = G^{\alpha \beta}g_{\alpha \beta}$?

Comment: @IgorKhavkine and if you meant $\mathbf{P}^T \mathbf{C} \mathbf{P}=[\mathbf{G}^1 | \mathbf{G}^2 | \mathbf{G}^1 \times \mathbf{G}^2 ]^T \mathbf{C} [\mathbf{G}_1 | \mathbf{G}_2 | \mathbf{G}_1 \times \mathbf{G}_2 ]$, then I agree I was using inverse to denote contravariant components in matrix form

Comment: Perhaps I got lost in the notation, but it seems to me that you have $[\mathbf{G}_1|\mathbf{G}_2] = \mathbf{F}_0$ and $[\mathbf{g}_1|\mathbf{g}_2] = \mathbf{F}_n$, so that unpacking the definitions of $\mathbf{F}$, $\mathbf{C}$ and $\mathbf{P}^T \mathbf{C} \mathbf{P}$ you get $\bar{C}_{\alpha\beta} = g_{\alpha\beta}$, but that is in its purely covariant form. If you insist on using $P^{-1}$ instead, then you get a mixed covariant-contravariant form, which I would write as $\bar{C}^\alpha_\beta = G^{\alpha\gamma} g_{\gamma\beta}$. Maybe that is what agrees with your intuition.